# Rails 4, Nested Attributes & Cocoon gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested, associations, cocoon-gem

I am trying to make an app with Rails 4.

I have nested attribute associations and am using cocoon gem to help with those form attributes.

I have models called project, package, participant and address.

The associations are:

**Project**

```
has_one :package
accepts_nested_attributes_for :package
```

**Package**

```
has_one :participant
accepts_nested_attributes_for: participant
```

**Participant**

```
belongs_to :package
has_many :addresses, as: :addressable
accepts_nested_attributes_for :addresses,  reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
```

**Address**

```
belongs_to :addressable, :polymorphic => true
```

`Address` is polymorphic.

I have an address fields form as:

```
<div class="nested-fields">

 <div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="form-inputs">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-3">
          <%= f.input :unit %>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3 col-xs-offset-1">
          <%= f.input :street_number %>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3 col-xs-offset-1">
          <%= f.input :street %>
        </div>
      </div>


    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-xs-offset-1">
      <%= f.input :time_zone %>
    </div>


  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-3">
      <%= f.input :main_address %>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-xs-offset-1">
      <%= f.input :project_offsite %>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
    </div>

  </div>
</div>

<div class = "debug" > <%= yield %> <%= debug(params) if Rails.env.development? %></div>
```

In my participant controller, I have:

```
def new
  @participant = Participant.new
  @participant.addresses_build
end

# GET /participants/1/edit
def edit
  @participant.addresses_build unless @participant.addresses
end
```

I have also included all of the address attributes in the participant strong params as nested attributes.

In my package controller, I have:

```
def new
  @package = Package.new
  @package.participants.build
  @package.participant.addresses_build unless @participant.addresses
end
```

I have also included the strong params in the package attributes (as nested attributes inside the participant_attributes).

I have a partial with fields for participant, which has:

```
<%= f.simple_fields_for :participant do |pf| %>
  <%= pf.error_notification %>

  <div class="form-inputs">

    <%= pf.input :description, :as => :text, :label => "What does participation involve", :input_html => {:rows => 10} %>

    <div class="row">

      <%= pf.input :eligibility, :as => :boolean, :label => false, inline_label: "Are there any eligibility criteria for participants?"  %>

      <%= pf.input :eligibility_criteria, :as => :text, :label => false, inline_label: "Are there any eligibility criteria for participants?",  :input_html => {:rows => 10} %>

      <%= pf.input :location_specific, :as => :boolean, :label => false, inline_label: "Is participation conducted at a specific location (as opposed to remote participation)?"  %>

      <div class="row">

        <div class="intpol2">

          Address for participation
        </div>

        <%= pf.simple_fields_for :addresses do |f| %>

          <%= render 'addresses/address_fields', f: f %>
        <% end %>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">

          <%= link_to_add_association 'Add an address', f, :addresses, partial: 'addresses/address_fields' %>

        </div>

      </div>

    </div>
  <% end %>
```

When I save all of this and try it, I get an error that says:

Association addresses doesn't exist on Package

I don't understand this error because the association is between address and participant. Participant belongs to package.

Can anyone see what I've done wrong?

Comment: Why are you showing us two controllers? is the same view rendered for both (which would be wrong). In the package controller you have an error in the `new` action: you check for a imho nil `@participant` to build the addresses (in new you should always build). Can you show use what is posted to the controller?

Comment: Not sure what you're suggesting. I have shown both the package and the participant controllers because participant belongs to package. In the package controller new action i build participant. In the participant controller I build address. What do you mean about showing what is posted to the controller?

Comment: Only one controller will be used to render the page, unless you are using ajax to render parts of the page (but why would you be using cocoon then?). In the logfile you can see what is posted to the controller (parameters), it will help to explain why saving would fail.

Comment: I don't know what you mean. Are you suggesting that my struggles arise out of the definition of new in the participant controller (and that I should rely on new in the package controller instead?

Comment: Only one controller is responsible for rendering a page. The routes determine which controller. The controller determines which views are rendered. When you create a new package. e.g. visit `/packages/new`, the `new` of the participant controller is never called. It is solely the package controller that will render the complete page, and thus complete form. This is pretty basic rails/MVC stuff.